# Calculate the percentage for each bin in the histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a plot that I made which looks like this

[image]

I want to find the percent of active vs inactive for each bin. I want the y-axis to be 100% and for each bin what percent of patients are active vs inactive for that bin.

This is the code I used to get this graph:

```
sns.distplot(inactive['inactivity_percentage'], kde = False, label="inactive")
plt.legend(labels=['active','inactive'])
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

I tried calculating the percentage in the data itself but since it is a continuous variable, I cant get the graph to look right. Within the existing graph can I get the percent for each bin?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to calculate the counts of active and inactive *with the same grid spacing*. Then calculate the ratios in each bins, and plot using bars

```
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.25, size=(2000,))
data2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.75, scale=0.1, size=(500,))

bins,step = np.linspace(0,1,11, retstep=True)
hist1,_ = np.histogram(data1, bins=bins)
hist2,_ = np.histogram(data2, bins=bins)
prop1 = 100*hist1/(hist1+hist2)
prop2 = 100*hist2/(hist1+hist2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=bins[:-1], height=prop1, bottom=0, align='edge', width=step)
ax.bar(x=bins[:-1], height=prop2, bottom=prop1, align='edge', width=step)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter())
```

[image]